# Running multiple python scripts to plot data in parallel

Tags: python, multithreading, matplotlib, plot

I'm looking for some advice as to how to organise a python project.

I have a directory `./scripts` containing several python scripts as below:

```
.
├── plot.py
├── __init__.py
└── scripts
    └── __init__.py
    └── sinx_1.py
    └── sinx_2.py
    └── sinx_3.py
```

Each of these scripts (`sinx_1.py` to `sinx_3.py`) are identical (in this example), and effectively plot some data using matplotlib to generate a pdf document using function `main()`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from numpy import arange, sin, pi


def main():
    t = arange(0, pi, 0.01)
    fig, ax = plt.subplots()
    ax.plot(t, sin(2*pi*t))
    plt.savefig('example-output.pdf')


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Ideally, what I'd like to do is have `plot.py` run `main()` from each of these `sinx_{1..3}.py` plot files in parallel using something like the `multithreading` package within python, but I can't figure out how to put it together. This is only an example of how I have the project laid out, but in practice I have several hundred plot scripts, so the speedup should be reasonably better than running them in serial.

Does anyone have any ideas on how to put this together using multithreading (or something completely different)?

Comment: If you don't really need to coordinate between these, I'd just write a bash script: `for f in scripts/*.py; do python3 $f &; done`. No need to pull out `multiprocessing` if you don't need to (note that threading here would likely not help you because of the GIL, threading isn't good for computation bound things).

Comment: Fair point. I did have a solution using GNU parallel: `parallel -j -8 python ::: "$python_plot_scripts"` that worked reasonable well, but figured that it'd be nice trying to find a pythonic solution.

Comment: Yep that works too. I'd say unless you need to invoke it programmatically, employing `multiprocessing` doesn't make it more pythonic.